# Object created inside scope deallocated even when used outside of scope

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, llvm, clang

**Update:** This was fixed in iOS 6.1 DP3 SDK.

I've tracked down a use-after-deallocated crash when building with ARC using the default release build configuration (debug seems to work fine). The problem occurs when creating an object inside an if-scope with a non-constant condition, assigning it to a variable from outside the scope and then only referencing the variable using Objective-C array or dictionary literals.

Here is the smallest reproducible case I've managed to find:

```
void test(BOOL arg)
{
    id obj = nil;

    if (arg) {
        obj = [NSObject new];
    }

    // obj already deallocated here
    @[obj];

    // but using NSArray works
    //[NSArray arrayWithObject:obj];

    // @[obj] works if obj is referenced i.e. by NSLog print out
    //NSLog(@"%@", obj);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        test(YES);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I build and run this with zombie objects enabled I get this error message:

```
-[NSObject retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x100109100
```

As I commented in the code it works fine if `obj` is referenced in some other way, like with `NSLog` or using `NSArray` instead. Have I misunderstood how objects are released with ARC and scopes or is this a optimization bug in LLVM or Clang?

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 with clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn). I can reproduce it when building for x86 64 bit for iOS simulator and Mac OS X and I'm quite sure the same problem occurs when building for ARM as the issue was first found when running release build on an iPhone.

I have filed and bug report to Apple and created an [open radar report](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2377401).

What, if anything, am I missing?

**Update**, did some more experiments:

As Gabro pointed out the compiler translates `@[]` to a `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]` statement so I did some tests:

```
// works
id a[] = {obj};
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:a count:1];

// does not work
const id *b = (id[]){obj};
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:b count:1];

// does not work
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id[]){obj} count:1];
```

So my guess is that this happens when combining ARC and anonymous C arrays.

Comment: according to Apple when you use the array literal, the compiler generates the following

     ```id objects[] = { obj };
     NSUInteger count = sizeof(objects) / sizeof(id);
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objects count:count]; ```

I wonder whether is there a bug due to going through play C arrays

Comment: Very odd.  I'd call it a bug.  I looked at the disassembly of the `@[obj]` and the `[NSArray arrayWithObject:obj]` variant for x86_64 with -Os optimization under LLVM 4.1; and the compiler inserts a call `obj_release` on `obj` before the `NSArray`.  Unless someone smarter than I chimes in, I'd call it a bug.

Comment: It's the new array literal syntax that was introduced with clang 3.1 take a look at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: I was suspicious about whether it was dependent on you not using the result of the `@[obj]` expression but I see by testing that fixing that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the following code both building for OSX (x86 64) and iOS Simulator and I cannot reproduce the bug

```
 void test(BOOL arg) {
     id obj = nil;

    if (arg) {
        obj = [NSObject new];
    }
    @[obj];
    NSLog(@"Hi there");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        test(YES);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code simply prints `Hi there` in the console and returns.

My configuration is the same of yours: XCode 4.5.2 and Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn) as a compiler.

**EDIT**

I also tried to compile from command line (after adding `#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>`
 at the beginning of the above example) using

```
clang -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation main.m
```

And the result was again

```
2012-12-03 12:47:45.647 a.out[39421:707] Hi there
```

**EDIT 2**
As pointed out in the comments it is possible to reproduce the bug increasing the optimization level over `-O0`. Summarizing:

```
clang -O0 -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation main.m
```

the program works as expected

```
clang -O1 -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation main.m
```

the bug presented in the question shows up. This is true with any optimization level over `-O0`

It's definitely a bug in the compiler.

Comment: That's weird. And you are sure your compiling with ARC?

Comment: What optimization level?  I **can** reproduce the OP's issue with any optimization level above `-O0`.  With no optimizations, the compiler appears not to over-release `obj` - otherwise it does.

Comment: Ah sorry now i see `-fobj-arc`. Yepp your example works for me also but if I add `-Os` as the default iOS release build configuration does it seems to over release.

Comment: confirmed, if you increase the optimization level above `-O0` it causes a segmentation fault. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything.  It's a compiler bug.